# How do I set the BayesianOptimization function to produce different values in each iteration?

Tags: performance, optimization

I used BayesianOptimization to set hyperparameters. I want it to generate different values for the hyperparameter every iteration and not generate duplicate values. But I don't know what to set so that the BayesianOptimization function produces different values every iteration.

Please guide me. Thanks.